# Насколько рандомен random.randint в python?

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```
import random
x=0
for i in range(10000):
    my_series = [random.randint(0, 11) for i in range(100)]
    x += 1 if len(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 1, my_series))) < len(list(filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, my_series))) else -1
    print(x)
```

Почему перевес всё время в минус хотя генерация списков рандомная и возможное количество чётных и нечётных значений одинаковое(от 0 до 11).

Comment: random - это генератор псевдослучайных чисел, https://habr.com/ru/company/pt/blog/156133/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что случаи, когда четных и нечетных одинаково, считаются в -1.

Если список `my_series` сделать нечетной длины, то `х` будет колебаться вокруг 0 (хотя могут случиться и довольно значительные отклонения).